# VS 2019 Remote Debugger failing for Azure App Service

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

Remote debugging an Azure App Service is failing due to the following error message:

[image]

I have both 64 and 32-bit remote debugging tools installed. The deployed application is an asp.net core application compiled in Azure Devops using `Any CPU`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Good question - did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Support said that it must be a 32 bit app. I never got around to verifying.

Answer (score 2):

You should change Platform in General settings in App Service Configuration from 64 bit to 32 bit
[link to screen of setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esvlT.png)